# Как работают smart_ptr при проверки установилось значение или нет

Tags: c++

Я хочу создать класс , который загружает файлы в отдельном потоке, мне нужно проверить если класс готов, похоже на перегрузку оператора условия, но как я посмотрел в интернете подобное сделать нельзя ( может не правильно искал). На сколько я знаю , когда создаешь smart ptr они устанавливают значение в nullptr и можно проверить через условие if(mySmartPtr){...} и если переменная создана сделать что-либо. Я могу конечно создавать дополнительную функцию для проверки, но хотелось бы знать как можно это реализовать, так же как в smart ptr

Comment: Скорее вам следует смотреть в сторону [std::promise](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо реализовать public метод `operator bool();`

```
class Foo
{
  public:
  operator bool()
  {
    // Ваш код обработки, в зависимости от того готов класс или нет,
    // возвращаете true или false
    return true;
  }
};
```

После этого ваш объект можно привести к типу bool, и использовать его в `if`:

```
Foo bar;
if (bar)
    std::cout << "object ready" << std::endl;
```

Comment: Если это С++11 или новее, еще лучше будет `explicit operator bool()`.